# How to get "add chrome extension " box

Tags: google-chrome

I want to get a chrome extension add box .But I don't know how. use html or javascript? the box is bellow!

[image]

Comment: Too lazy to search in Google?

Comment: Sorry ,the picture doesn't display directly. please click "enter image description here" to see the picture.

Comment: Thank you Raptor. I searched .But can't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. use inline install, here is the document: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation